# User stuck on page until ChatGPT returns an answer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, openai-api

Need to stop the request so that the user can leave the page whenever he wants. Right now even after aborting the user is stuck in the page till the request is done.

Current JS:

```
var xhr = $.post(url, data, (response) => {
    if (response.success) {

    }
});

$('a').click(function() {
    xhr.abort();
});
```

Current PHP:

```
$open_ai_key = get_field('openai_api_key', 'options');
$open_ai = new Orhanerday\OpenAi\OpenAi($open_ai_key);

$complete = $open_ai->chat([
  'model'    => 'gpt-4',
  'messages' => [
    [
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => $prompt_with_direction
    ],
  ],
  'temperature'       => 0,
  'top_p'             => 1,
  'max_tokens'        => 1024,
  'frequency_penalty' => 0,
  'presence_penalty'  => 0,
]);

$text = json_decode($complete, true);
$text = $text['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
wp_send_json_success($text);
```

Comment: If you have an open PHP session other requests will block until that session is closed. Use [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close) before a long running request.

Comment: @Sammitch tyvm, if you post a full answer I can mark this as the solution